# What could be the sequence of events happening in a flyback converter running in no-load in (1) open loop mode, (2) with closed loop feedback?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, control-system

A flyback converter is a non-direct energy transfer converter feeding a load whose variation is not in our control. We can imagine that the coupled inductor at very negligible or low load (high resistance) would draw very low current to magnetize the core only. However this magnetizing current will transfer to the secondary coil from the primary coil when the switch turns off. This current will charge the filter capacitor and the capacitor will keep on building its voltage since it has nowhere to discharge. So we may assume that first this will breakdown if we select a switch of higher voltage blocking capability. Can closed loop system give protection against this phenomenon or do we need any separate circuit to prevent this situation?

Comment: Arindam, if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Can closed loop system give protection against this phenomenon or do
> we need any separate circuit to prevent this situation?*

This is absolutely what happens and, we will reduce the duty cycle as load current drops. If the load current becomes too small we may exit regular cyclic energy transfers at a very low duty cycle and, enter pulse skipping mode where, effectively, the control pulses are halted until the output voltage has fallen below a certain value.

In short, we **must always** use a control system wrapped around the flyback circuit if the load current is expected to fall to low values.